# Is it possible to skip input from a file & start scanning from somewhere in the middle?

Tags: c, input, scanf, skip

In C, I want to scan only some lines from input to save runtime of my program. For eg:

Say my input file contains some random numbers like:

```
5 1
1 2
1 7
5 6
3 4
1 6
2 5 3
1 5 4
3 1 1
```

Here I want to skip all the numbers that are in doubles and start from those that are in triples i.e.

```
2 5 3
1 5 4
3 1 1
```

Can I redirect the scanf() such that it starts scanning from somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fseek.html) function to jump the file cursor to an arbitrary offset in the file, provided that you know the number of bytes that you need to skip.

If you don't know in advance how many characters you need to skip over, your best option would be to continuously read lines from the file and skip over those that don't match your criteria.  In your case, you could skip all lines that just have one space character in them, and could resume reading once you find a line that has two spaces in it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well, the input file has millions of lines & I tried with the second option of your answer, & that gave me TLE. Though thanks for fseek idea, I'll try & see if it helps..Thank You.

Comment: @user81910- If you're under huge time pressure, you could consider using `mmap` to load the file directly into memory, then scanning over it as a giant `char` array to try to find the line you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can read and ignore data until you reach what you want. For example, read a line with `fgets`, then use `sscanf` to try to convert that line to three numbers. If the return from `sscanf` isn't 3, it couldn't convert three numbers, so continue to the next line. When `sscanf` does return 3, then you can save the results in an array (or whatever).

To truly skip to a later point in the file, you'd need to know the offset to skip to, and feed that to `fseek`. That seems unlikely to apply here though.

If your file is large *and* you know (for sure) that it consists solely of 2-number lines followed by 3-number lines, you could do something like a binary search to find the first 3-number line. You'd start by finding the file length, then seek (about) halfway into the file. Read and ignore one line (because you probably didn't seek to the beginning of a line). Then read the next line and try to convert it as above. If it has three numbers, then you're past the point that the three-number lines started, so try again about halfway back to the beginning (and if it's only a 2-number line, halfway further to the end).

You probably don't want to keep this up too long -- when you're within a few kilobytes (or so) of the beginning of the three-number lines, it's probably faster to just read sequentially until you find the beginning instead of doing a lot more seeking to find exactly the right point.

Comment: +1 thats *amazing* how similar our answers were. Dropping mine and up-voting yours.

Comment: @WhozCraig: They are a lot alike, now that you mention it (or were, anyway -- I've added a possible optimization, since the OP says the file is pretty big).

Comment: Wish I could up-vote it again. Thats a pretty nice optimization considering what we're given to work with. In theory, ~25+ seeks will home you to within a few lines of where you want to be, which in't bad at all for a file that is upwards of 4gB. For a few million lines, it should home in as little as 20 seeks.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention (Sorry!) that I know how many lines will have doublets(say N) & I have to start reading from (N+1) line. I just didn't knew how to skip those N lines. Also after finishing scanning triplets, I have to scan only few of doublets. So I guess fseek will work. Thank You very much for your time and answer..!